# shell quoting behavior

Tags: linux, shell, quoting

I just learned that, quoting make a huge difference in some cases, and I did something to test it, here is what I just did,

```
$ xfs=$(find . -type f -perm -111)  #find all files with x-perm
$ echo "$xfs"
./b.out 
./a.out
$ echo $xfs
./b.out ./a.out  #why all in one line, but the above takes two?
```

If `$xfs` contains `\n`, AFAIK, `echo -e` will expand `\n`, but how can `echo "$xfs"` take 2 lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any whitespace is normally in shell considered to be an argument separator. Thus, your first example has two arguments. `echo` prints the arguments separated by one space, and that's the behaviour you see in your second example.

However, when you use quotes, anything between them is one argument, and it is printed literally. The one argument in your first example already contains a newline, so it is printed with a newline.

The `-e` option from the `bash` `echo` builtin regulates the expansion of escape sequences like `\n`; however, you don't have any escape sequences. The variable contains a literal newline.